How can I remove a screw from the hinge of a kitchen cupboard door
I am redoing my kitchen and I have the cupboard door off but cannot for the life of me get the last little screw out. It is totally stripped. The rubber band trick didn't work and everything else I am reading seems like it will damage my door. Any suggestions?

What does "redoing my kitchen" mean? Are the cabinets being salvaged? Are the doors and hinges being reused? Please revise to provide more factual detail so we understand the parameters of the situation. A photo would be dandy.

If you can't get the screw out of the cupboard door, remove the screws holding the hinge to the cabinet frame. Then remove the door, hinge and all.
If your process of "redoing" the kitchen involves removing and replacing the cabinets, then just rip the door off or use a hammer.
If you are replacing cabinets and want to donate the old cabinets, see my suggestion at the top of the answer.
